# Calculate affiliate revenue neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to calculate the revenue of each instructor from neo4j graph database with the following query

```
MATCH (Main:Instructor), (Sub1:Instructor),(Sub2:Instructor),(Sub3:Instructor),
 (Tran1:Transaction),(Tran2:Transaction),(Tran3:Transaction) 
WHERE Sub1.affiliateTo = Main.instructorID AND Sub2.affiliateTo = Sub1.instructorID 
 AND Sub3.affiliateTo = Sub2.instructorID   AND Main.instructorID <> Sub1.instructorID  
 AND Sub1.instructorID <> Sub2.instructorID and Sub2.instructorID <> Sub3.instructorID 
 AND Tran1.instructorID =Sub1.instructorID AND Tran2.instructorID =Sub2.instructorID 
 AND Tran3.instructorID =Sub3.instructorID  
RETURN Main.name as Name,
 ((Tran1.transactionAMT*20/100)+(Tran2.transactionAMT*10/100)+(Tran3.transactionAMT*5/100)) 
 as revenue
```

But it do not give the correct result.It gives same amount for all users as follows

[image]

The rules for the calculation is as follows.

- Each instructor gives (20%) discount to another members via personal coupon
- The initial instructor gets 20% of level one subscriptions
- The initial instructor gets 10% of level two subscriptions
- The initial instructor gets 5% of level three subscriptions

**EDIT** - I have created the following relation as well

```
MATCH (inst:Instructor),(tran:Transaction) 
WHERE inst.instructorID = tran.instructorID 
CREATE (inst)-[r:PAID]->(tran) 
RETURN r

MATCH (main:Instructor),(sub:Instructor) 
WHERE  main.instructorID = sub.affiliateTo  
 AND main.instructorID <> main.affiliateTo  
CREATE (main)-[r:CHILD_INSTRUCTOR]->(sub) 
RETURN r
```

But it do not give the correct result. It gives same amount for all users as follows

I need to find the revenue for each instructor

**Instructor data**

> "{""name"":""Wilber Woodson"",""affiliateTo"":0,""instructorID"":1}"
>   "{""name"":""Rosaria Rock"",""affiliateTo"":0,""instructorID"":2}"
>   "{""name"":""Inger Ikner"",""affiliateTo"":0,""instructorID"":3}"
>   "{""name"":""Greta Workman"",""affiliateTo"":0,""instructorID"":4}"
>   "{""name"":""Kevin Van Gundy"",""affiliateTo"":4,""instructorID"":5}"
>   "{""name"":""Michael Hunger"",""affiliateTo"":1,""instructorID"":6}"
>   "{""name"":""Bryce Merkl
>   Sasaki"",""affiliateTo"":2,""instructorID"":7}" "{""name"":""Nicole
>   White"",""affiliateTo"":3,""instructorID"":8}" "{""name"":""Elsy
>   Eckhardt "",""affiliateTo"":4,""instructorID"":9}" "{""name"":""Loreta
>   Larrimore "",""affiliateTo"":4,""instructorID"":10}"
>   "{""name"":""Aliza Albrecht "",""affiliateTo"":4,""instructorID"":11}"
>   "{""name"":""Sharyn Santini "",""affiliateTo"":4,""instructorID"":12}"
>   "{""name"":""Eugenie Elling "",""affiliateTo"":1,""instructorID"":13}"
>   "{""name"":""Kristofer Kirshner
>   "",""affiliateTo"":2,""instructorID"":14}" "{""name"":""Irving Izzard
>   "",""affiliateTo"":3,""instructorID"":15}" "{""name"":""Elina Enfinger
>   "",""affiliateTo"":2,""instructorID"":16}" "{""name"":""Max Moschella
>   "",""affiliateTo"":1,""instructorID"":17}" "{""name"":""Elena Elwood
>   "",""affiliateTo"":4,""instructorID"":18}" "{""name"":""Jeanmarie
>   Jaffe "",""affiliateTo"":1,""instructorID"":19}" "{""name"":""Brianne
>   Buelow "",""affiliateTo"":8,""instructorID"":20}" "{""name"":""Wanda
>   Wrinkle "",""affiliateTo"":11,""instructorID"":21}"
>   "{""name"":""Jeffery Jackman
>   "",""affiliateTo"":14,""instructorID"":22}" "{""name"":""Alonzo Alaniz
>   "",""affiliateTo"":11,""instructorID"":23}" "{""name"":""Willy Wickert
>   "",""affiliateTo"":8,""instructorID"":24}" "{""name"":""Maud
>   Maclachlan "",""affiliateTo"":6,""instructorID"":25}"
>   "{""name"":""Tarsha Teeter "",""affiliateTo"":5,""instructorID"":26}"
>   "{""name"":""Maureen Morrissey
>   "",""affiliateTo"":11,""instructorID"":27}" "{""name"":""Albert
>   Adamczyk "",""affiliateTo"":9,""instructorID"":28}" "{""name"":""Niki
>   Neidig "",""affiliateTo"":9,""instructorID"":29}" "{""name"":""Deedra
>   Disandro "",""affiliateTo"":16,""instructorID"":30}"
>   "{""name"":""Melynda Mehl "",""affiliateTo"":14,""instructorID"":31}"
>   "{""name"":""Hans Hornberger
>   "",""affiliateTo"":17,""instructorID"":32}" "{""name"":""Corrie
>   Calabrese "",""affiliateTo"":9,""instructorID"":33}" "{""name"":""Max
>   Demarzi"",""affiliateTo"":19,""instructorID"":34}"
>   "{""name"":""Arletha Azevedo
>   "",""affiliateTo"":10,""instructorID"":35}" "{""name"":""Berta
>   Burchill "",""affiliateTo"":9,""instructorID"":36}"
>   "{""name"":""Alfred Arcuri "",""affiliateTo"":5,""instructorID"":37}"
>   "{""name"":""Claretta Corrales
>   "",""affiliateTo"":19,""instructorID"":38}" "{""name"":""Tia Twersky
>   "",""affiliateTo"":10,""instructorID"":39}" "{""name"":""Sharell
>   Sollers "",""affiliateTo"":6,""instructorID"":40}"
>   "{""name"":""Catrice Crays "",""affiliateTo"":17,""instructorID"":41}"
>   "{""name"":""Dina Dreher "",""affiliateTo"":18,""instructorID"":42}"
>   "{""name"":""Branda Beauchamp
>   "",""affiliateTo"":11,""instructorID"":43}" "{""name"":""Pennie Profit
>   "",""affiliateTo"":19,""instructorID"":44}" "{""name"":""Hank
>   Taylor"",""affiliateTo"":17,""instructorID"":45}"
>   "{""name"":""Bethanie Bober
>   "",""affiliateTo"":13,""instructorID"":46}" "{""name"":""Barney Brode
>   "",""affiliateTo"":14,""instructorID"":47}" "{""name"":""Pat Pless
>   "",""affiliateTo"":18,""instructorID"":48}" "{""name"":""Anastasia
>   Asberry "",""affiliateTo"":10,""instructorID"":49}"
>   "{""name"":""Emmett Eugene "",""affiliateTo"":13,""instructorID"":50}"
>   "{""name"":""Vicky Vivian "",""affiliateTo"":40,""instructorID"":51}"
>   "{""name"":""Zoe Zenz "",""affiliateTo"":48,""instructorID"":52}"
>   "{""name"":""Sunshine Stobaugh
>   "",""affiliateTo"":35,""instructorID"":53}" "{""name"":""Kemberly
>   Knisley "",""affiliateTo"":32,""instructorID"":54}"
>   "{""name"":""Jackeline Jong
>   "",""affiliateTo"":30,""instructorID"":55}" "{""name"":""Katia Kohout
>   "",""affiliateTo"":29,""instructorID"":56}" "{""name"":""Lupe Levar
>   "",""affiliateTo"":29,""instructorID"":57}" "{""name"":""Marcel Martir
>   "",""affiliateTo"":41,""instructorID"":58}" "{""name"":""Trisha Tabron
>   "",""affiliateTo"":30,""instructorID"":59}" "{""name"":""Sabina
>   Shriner "",""affiliateTo"":33,""instructorID"":60}"
>   "{""name"":""Raphael Roots "",""affiliateTo"":29,""instructorID"":61}"
>   "{""name"":""May Michels "",""affiliateTo"":32,""instructorID"":62}"
>   "{""name"":""Adina Ausmus "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":63}"
>   "{""name"":""Darci Diggins "",""affiliateTo"":41,""instructorID"":64}"
>   "{""name"":""Carri Colas "",""affiliateTo"":40,""instructorID"":65}"
>   "{""name"":""Claudine Carrow
>   "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":66}" "{""name"":""Casimira
>   Clyburn "",""affiliateTo"":48,""instructorID"":67}" "{""name"":""Quyen
>   Quinones "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":68}"
>   "{""name"":""Basilia Bobadilla
>   "",""affiliateTo"":47,""instructorID"":69}" "{""name"":""Jamika Jorden
>   "",""affiliateTo"":36,""instructorID"":70}" "{""name"":""Ilene
>   Isenberg "",""affiliateTo"":39,""instructorID"":71}"
>   "{""name"":""Ernestina Enoch
>   "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":72}" "{""name"":""Alexa Abila
>   "",""affiliateTo"":46,""instructorID"":73}" "{""name"":""Veronique
>   Vanasse "",""affiliateTo"":30,""instructorID"":74}"
>   "{""name"":""Lorrine Lowell
>   "",""affiliateTo"":42,""instructorID"":75}" "{""name"":""Loretta
>   Linehan "",""affiliateTo"":40,""instructorID"":76}" "{""name"":""Len
>   Loar "",""affiliateTo"":37,""instructorID"":77}" "{""name"":""Fumiko
>   Fairfield "",""affiliateTo"":44,""instructorID"":78}"
>   "{""name"":""Alonzo Astin "",""affiliateTo"":30,""instructorID"":79}"
>   "{""name"":""Janyce Jarrells
>   "",""affiliateTo"":32,""instructorID"":80}" "{""name"":""Janay Jonason
>   "",""affiliateTo"":40,""instructorID"":81}" "{""name"":""Geri Garret
>   "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":82}" "{""name"":""Dario Derrico
>   "",""affiliateTo"":32,""instructorID"":83}" "{""name"":""Tami Toppin
>   "",""affiliateTo"":40,""instructorID"":84}" "{""name"":""Rickey Ryles
>   "",""affiliateTo"":41,""instructorID"":85}" "{""name"":""Lenny Lago
>   "",""affiliateTo"":30,""instructorID"":86}" "{""name"":""Darnell
>   Doering "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":87}"
>   "{""name"":""Cathryn Cascio
>   "",""affiliateTo"":26,""instructorID"":88}" "{""name"":""Isidra Islas
>   "",""affiliateTo"":45,""instructorID"":89}" "{""name"":""Ray Ravenell
>   "",""affiliateTo"":47,""instructorID"":90}" "{""name"":""Lashanda Loeb
>   "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":91}" "{""name"":""Margareta
>   Meli "",""affiliateTo"":35,""instructorID"":92}" "{""name"":""Valene
>   Vannest "",""affiliateTo"":35,""instructorID"":93}" "{""name"":""Mandi
>   Marton "",""affiliateTo"":30,""instructorID"":94}" "{""name"":""Breana
>   Beaudoin "",""affiliateTo"":41,""instructorID"":95}"
>   "{""name"":""Rudolf Robuck "",""affiliateTo"":26,""instructorID"":96}"
>   "{""name"":""Tarsha Thibeau
>   "",""affiliateTo"":46,""instructorID"":97}" "{""name"":""Tobi Trieu
>   "",""affiliateTo"":44,""instructorID"":98}" "{""name"":""Norbert Nolte
>   "",""affiliateTo"":32,""instructorID"":99}" "{""name"":""Jessika Judah
>   "",""affiliateTo"":46,""instructorID"":100}" "{""name"":""Jonathon
>   Jacobo "",""affiliateTo"":30,""instructorID"":101}" "{""name"":""Trula
>   Tobler "",""affiliateTo"":33,""instructorID"":102}"
>   "{""name"":""Clarence Chalker
>   "",""affiliateTo"":47,""instructorID"":103}" "{""name"":""Palma
>   Porterfield "",""affiliateTo"":29,""instructorID"":104}"
>   "{""name"":""Felisa Foland
>   "",""affiliateTo"":42,""instructorID"":105}" "{""name"":""Autumn Amore
>   "",""affiliateTo"":47,""instructorID"":106}" "{""name"":""Aurore Atnip
>   "",""affiliateTo"":29,""instructorID"":107}" "{""name"":""Willis
>   Wakeman "",""affiliateTo"":36,""instructorID"":108}"
>   "{""name"":""Marvella Mcfarlin
>   "",""affiliateTo"":29,""instructorID"":109}" "{""name"":""Shawanna
>   Starks "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":110}"
>   "{""name"":""Christia Colligan
>   "",""affiliateTo"":36,""instructorID"":111}" "{""name"":""Mirian
>   Mccaskill "",""affiliateTo"":35,""instructorID"":112}"
>   "{""name"":""Dustin Darrigo
>   "",""affiliateTo"":46,""instructorID"":113}" "{""name"":""Bettie
>   Bradburn "",""affiliateTo"":43,""instructorID"":114}"
>   "{""name"":""Voncile Vanetten
>   "",""affiliateTo"":37,""instructorID"":115}" "{""name"":""Alonso Ahart
>   "",""affiliateTo"":41,""instructorID"":116}" "{""name"":""Harold
>   Hogsett "",""affiliateTo"":47,""instructorID"":117}"
>   "{""name"":""Fernando Fremont
>   "",""affiliateTo"":43,""instructorID"":118}" "{""name"":""Sharee Spina
>   "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":119}" "{""name"":""Mitsuko
>   Mcghie "",""affiliateTo"":35,""instructorID"":120}"
>   "{""name"":""Mildred Mertes
>   "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":121}" "{""name"":""Andre Arnett
>   "",""affiliateTo"":43,""instructorID"":122}" "{""name"":""Veola
>   Vazquez "",""affiliateTo"":40,""instructorID"":123}"
>   "{""name"":""Raisa Rogue "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":124}"
>   "{""name"":""Toni Tope "",""affiliateTo"":39,""instructorID"":125}"
>   "{""name"":""Della Damiano
>   "",""affiliateTo"":36,""instructorID"":126}" "{""name"":""Bethel
>   Balsley "",""affiliateTo"":39,""instructorID"":127}"
>   "{""name"":""Angelia Ahumada
>   "",""affiliateTo"":37,""instructorID"":128}" "{""name"":""Jerrie
>   Jimenes "",""affiliateTo"":44,""instructorID"":129}"
>   "{""name"":""Deedee Dave "",""affiliateTo"":35,""instructorID"":130}"
>   "{""name"":""Stasia Stamant
>   "",""affiliateTo"":46,""instructorID"":131}" "{""name"":""Rey Roloff
>   "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":132}" "{""name"":""Lyman Lade
>   "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":133}" "{""name"":""Annelle
>   Athey "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":134}" "{""name"":""Darcel
>   Dawe "",""affiliateTo"":34,""instructorID"":135}" "{""name"":""Kristi
>   Kyllonen "",""affiliateTo"":27,""instructorID"":136}"
>   "{""name"":""Ivey Inskeep "",""affiliateTo"":46,""instructorID"":137}"
>   "{""name"":""Wilhelmina Wolken
>   "",""affiliateTo"":32,""instructorID"":138}" "{""name"":""Shavon
>   Strouse "",""affiliateTo"":39,""instructorID"":139}"
>   "{""name"":""Barney Brim "",""affiliateTo"":39,""instructorID"":140}"
>   "{""name"":""Fallon Fagundes
>   "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":141}" "{""name"":""Tonisha
>   Trumbull "",""affiliateTo"":43,""instructorID"":142}"
>   "{""name"":""Aleshia Amsler
>   "",""affiliateTo"":28,""instructorID"":143}" "{""name"":""Marianne
>   Macaulay "",""affiliateTo"":44,""instructorID"":144}"
>   "{""name"":""Kimbra Kral "",""affiliateTo"":42,""instructorID"":145}"
>   "{""name"":""Alfonzo Alleman
>   "",""affiliateTo"":43,""instructorID"":146}" "{""name"":""Fletcher
>   Fiorillo "",""affiliateTo"":43,""instructorID"":147}"
>   "{""name"":""Josue Judd "",""affiliateTo"":47,""instructorID"":148}"
>   "{""name"":""Clair Carreira
>   "",""affiliateTo"":38,""instructorID"":149}" "{""name"":""Kyoko
>   Kimbrell "",""affiliateTo"":46,""instructorID"":150}"

**Transaction Data**

> "{""transactionAMT"":20,""transactionID"":1,""instructorID"":1}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":20,""transactionID"":2,""instructorID"":2}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":20,""transactionID"":3,""instructorID"":3}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":20,""transactionID"":4,""instructorID"":4}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":5,""instructorID"":5}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":6,""instructorID"":6}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":7,""instructorID"":7}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":8,""instructorID"":8}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":9,""instructorID"":9}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":10,""instructorID"":10}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":11,""instructorID"":11}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":12,""instructorID"":12}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":13,""instructorID"":13}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":14,""instructorID"":14}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":15,""instructorID"":15}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":16,""instructorID"":16}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":17,""instructorID"":17}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":18,""instructorID"":18}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":19,""instructorID"":19}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":20,""instructorID"":20}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":21,""instructorID"":21}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":22,""instructorID"":22}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":23,""instructorID"":23}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":24,""instructorID"":24}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":25,""instructorID"":25}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":26,""instructorID"":26}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":27,""instructorID"":27}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":28,""instructorID"":28}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":29,""instructorID"":29}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":30,""instructorID"":30}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":31,""instructorID"":31}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":32,""instructorID"":32}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":33,""instructorID"":33}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":34,""instructorID"":34}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":35,""instructorID"":35}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":36,""instructorID"":36}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":37,""instructorID"":37}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":38,""instructorID"":38}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":39,""instructorID"":39}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":40,""instructorID"":40}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":41,""instructorID"":41}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":42,""instructorID"":42}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":43,""instructorID"":43}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":44,""instructorID"":44}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":45,""instructorID"":45}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":46,""instructorID"":46}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":47,""instructorID"":47}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":48,""instructorID"":48}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":49,""instructorID"":49}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":50,""instructorID"":50}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":51,""instructorID"":51}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":52,""instructorID"":52}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":53,""instructorID"":53}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":54,""instructorID"":54}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":55,""instructorID"":55}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":56,""instructorID"":56}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":57,""instructorID"":57}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":58,""instructorID"":58}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":59,""instructorID"":59}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":60,""instructorID"":60}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":61,""instructorID"":61}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":62,""instructorID"":62}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":63,""instructorID"":63}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":64,""instructorID"":64}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":65,""instructorID"":65}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":66,""instructorID"":66}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":67,""instructorID"":67}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":68,""instructorID"":68}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":69,""instructorID"":69}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":70,""instructorID"":70}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":71,""instructorID"":71}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":72,""instructorID"":72}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":73,""instructorID"":73}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":74,""instructorID"":74}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":75,""instructorID"":75}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":76,""instructorID"":76}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":77,""instructorID"":77}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":78,""instructorID"":78}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":79,""instructorID"":79}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":80,""instructorID"":80}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":81,""instructorID"":81}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":82,""instructorID"":82}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":83,""instructorID"":83}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":84,""instructorID"":84}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":85,""instructorID"":85}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":86,""instructorID"":86}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":87,""instructorID"":87}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":88,""instructorID"":88}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":89,""instructorID"":89}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":90,""instructorID"":90}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":91,""instructorID"":91}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":92,""instructorID"":92}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":93,""instructorID"":93}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":94,""instructorID"":94}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":95,""instructorID"":95}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":96,""instructorID"":96}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":97,""instructorID"":97}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":98,""instructorID"":98}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":99,""instructorID"":99}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":100,""instructorID"":100}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":101,""instructorID"":101}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":102,""instructorID"":102}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":103,""instructorID"":103}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":104,""instructorID"":104}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":105,""instructorID"":105}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":106,""instructorID"":106}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":107,""instructorID"":107}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":108,""instructorID"":108}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":109,""instructorID"":109}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":110,""instructorID"":110}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":111,""instructorID"":111}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":112,""instructorID"":112}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":113,""instructorID"":113}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":114,""instructorID"":114}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":115,""instructorID"":115}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":116,""instructorID"":116}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":117,""instructorID"":117}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":118,""instructorID"":118}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":119,""instructorID"":119}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":120,""instructorID"":120}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":121,""instructorID"":121}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":122,""instructorID"":122}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":123,""instructorID"":123}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":124,""instructorID"":124}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":125,""instructorID"":125}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":126,""instructorID"":126}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":127,""instructorID"":127}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":128,""instructorID"":128}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":129,""instructorID"":129}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":130,""instructorID"":130}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":131,""instructorID"":131}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":132,""instructorID"":132}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":133,""instructorID"":133}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":134,""instructorID"":134}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":135,""instructorID"":135}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":136,""instructorID"":136}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":137,""instructorID"":137}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":138,""instructorID"":138}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":139,""instructorID"":139}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":140,""instructorID"":140}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":141,""instructorID"":141}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":142,""instructorID"":142}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":143,""instructorID"":143}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":144,""instructorID"":144}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":145,""instructorID"":145}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":146,""instructorID"":146}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":147,""instructorID"":147}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":148,""instructorID"":148}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":149,""instructorID"":149}"
>   "{""transactionAMT"":16,""transactionID"":150,""instructorID"":150}"

Comment: Your data is modeled for relational dbs, as you're relying on ids on different nodes to be used like foreign keys. In graph databases, foreign keys tend not to be used, they are replaced with relationships between related nodes. I'd definitely recommend changing your model accordingly.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I created two relations also \n MATCH (inst:Instructor),(tran:Transaction) WHERE inst.instructorID = tran.instructorID CREATE (inst)-[r:PAID]->(tran) RETURN r

MATCH (main:Instructor),(sub:Instructor) WHERE  main.instructorID = sub.affiliateTo  AND main.instructorID <> main.affiliateTo  CREATE (main)-[r:CHILD_INSTRUCTOR]->(sub) RETURN r
But it do not give the correct result.It gives same amount for all users as follows.But is it possible to get data with like this relation?

Comment: So for all instructors, going out to 3 sub instructors following :CHILD_INSTRUCTOR relationships, you want to calculate the total revenue pulled from the child instructors according to the formula given, and you're excluding whatever the instructor is paid directly. Is that correct? Do you also want this for instructors that have less than 3 sub instructors (say only 2, or just 1?)

Comment: I am trying to calculate the revenue from the child level,(20% of first+10% of second + 5% of third)>This need to include 1st and second and third.I am new in graph datanase.IS the relation is correct? what can you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you added relationship between your nodes, the query can be greatly simplified.

We need paths from each instructor to child instructors up to 3 levels down, and depending on how far down, we can get the appropriate percentage to run the calculations on the given transactions, then sum it all up.

Here's an example query that should work, though it will report on any instructor with at least one child instructor, instead of only instructors with at least 3 levels down of child instructors.

```
with [20.0, 10.0, 5.0] as percents
// subs up to 3 levels down and their transactions
match (i:Instructor)-[r:CHILD_INSTRUCTOR*..3]->()-[:PAID]->(t:Transaction)
// use number of traversals to determine percent
with i, percents[size(r) - 1] as percent, t
with i, t.transactionAMT * percent / 100.0 as cut
return i.name as Name, sum(cut) as revenue
```